# Java - Finding whether Cookies Disabled or not

Tags: java, servlets

HI,

Is there any way I can find whether the cookies are disabled or not on the client browser. I have seen some posts saying to find using redirect URL, but there is no code how to do that . Can anyone please help me with a sample code to check this.

Please note that I want this to be done using Java only (no javascript please)

Thanks!
Srinivas

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you test if cookies are enabled in Java/J2EE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318938/how-do-you-test-if-cookies-are-enabled-in-java-j2ee)

Answer (score 1):

you could set a cookie on the startsite and try to read it on the following sites, if your cookie can't be read the user has either disabled them or has deleted your cookie